# fav icon in index.html file not work in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, favicon

fav icon does not display in file in index.html in vue.js project despite of the correct path ?

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="./src/assets/images/logo.png" type="image/png" sizes="96x96">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>demo</title>
  </head>
```

Comment: did you clear your cache?

Comment: yes but still not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your index.html is located in your public directory, your favicon logo image should also be located inside the public directory since everything on src/ is not actually being served but compiled by webpack and therefore not accessible to the index.html file.

Comment: This is what I was thinking. Do you know how OP would solve this?